# query base class in Morphia doesn't work

Tags: java, mongodb, inheritance, morphia

I'm using Mongo java driver 3.0.0-beta2 and morphia 0.110. 
I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Animal {
    protected ObjectID id;
}
@Entity
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public String name;
}
```

Both are registered with morphia at initialization.

I have an id to an Animal stored as a Cat object. 
this query returns null :

```
datastore.get(Animal.class, id);
```

while this query is givinig me the correct object :

```
datastore.get(Cat.class, id);
```

Am I doing it wrong or is that a bug? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to define the collection for these types of queries to work (this is from the official documentation):

```
@Entity("animals") abstract class Animal { String name; }
@Entity("animals") Cat extends Animal { ... }
@Entity("animals") Dog extends Animal { ... }

List<Animal> animals = ds.createQuery(Animal.class).asList();
```

But I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe generics would be a better solution (to provide a generic "get by id")?